# Why can't I resolve the dependencies for GeoTools maven quickstart?

Tags: maven, geotools

POM is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>10-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I get the error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tutorial: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.geotools:tutorial:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:10-SNAPSHOT, org.geotools:gt-swing:jar:10-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:10-SNAPSHOT in maven2- repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2) -> [Help 1]`

Why can't it resolve the artifacts. GeoTools has other instructions (which I can't get to work) but I'd like to know whats wrong with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue occurs because the `org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:10-SNAPSHOT` does not exist at either `http://download.java.net/maven/2` or `http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools`. All you have to do is define the `snapshot repository` for the `GeoTools` as it is mentioned at  [the GeoTools:Maven Quick Start](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html) as the following: -

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Defining the snapshot did not work for me either. But I guess I did ask "why can't" not "how can".

Comment: It has worked for me. But there is no mention of a "snapshot repository" in the GeoToos Quick start, or am I wrong?

Comment: or build the jars locally (which is the usual use for SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more.  opengeo.org url is invalid

Comment: @Kieveli - check the quickstart, opengeo is now known as boundless so the repo is at http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main

Comment: And boundless is now purchased, the community has migrated to https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ and https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/ open source geospatial foundation repository.

Answer (score 23):

Some of the repositories in above answers have been moved to alternative addresses. Adding the following repositories solved the issue for me.

```
 <repository>
      <id>osgeo-alt</id>
      <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
       <id>geomajas</id>
       <name>Geomajas Maven Repository</name>
       <url>http://maven.geomajas.org/(http://maven.geomajas.org/)</url>
 </repository>
```

Comment: There is also a snapshots repository at https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/

Answer (score 5):

Current available osgeo repo:

```
<repository>      
  <id>geotools</id>
  <name>Geotools repository</name>
  <!--<url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>-->
  <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://download.java.net/maven/2 **repository is gone**

**New updates**, New way to add geotools dependency in your project, copy below xml file in your build.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>19-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

It works

Comment: Please update your answer to reflect the geotools community migration to OSGeo nexus repository https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ and https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/

Answer (score 1):

You should add Boundless repository and write *https* indtead of *http*:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

It will make the things work.

Comment: The boundless repository has been decommissioned as the company has been purchased. The community has moved to the open source geospatial foundation nexus repository set up for this purpose (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ and https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/)

Comment: Can't find ```gt-api``` there.

Comment: gt-api is in there just search for gt-api