# Unable to find the dependencies in Maven for the GeoTools Quickstart

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, geotools

I've looked at this past thread but none of the answers yielded any luck: [Why can't I resolve the dependencies for GeoTools maven quickstart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225573/why-cant-i-resolve-the-dependencies-for-geotools-maven-quickstart).

I have these errors:

Dependency 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:19-SNAPSHOT' not found

Dependency 'org.geotools:gt-swing:19-SNAPSHOT' not found

Here's the GeoTools IntelliJ Quickstart: https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/intellij.html

Here's the POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>toutorial</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>toutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>19-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>osgeo</id>
      <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
      <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Are the links I am using outdated? I have tried using different links for repositories as suggested in the thread I linked above, but none of them seemed to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find avalanche version of gt-shapefile from [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-shapefile?repo=boundless)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geotools lib suddenly disappear from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226545/geotools-lib-suddenly-disappear-from-repository)

Comment: You have declared the OSGeo release repository, but are requesting snapshot versions. Request a non-snapshot version, or make sure that you include the snapshot repository in your repositories configuration.